# React Native and Redux: Component doesn´t rerender after state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a component connected to my store. 
This component dispatches an Action and changes the state correctly ([see Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkNHd.png)).
But my Component should display this state change. But it doesn´t rerender.

Here is my code:

My Redux store, reducer and Action is like this:

```
//store.js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import  thunk  from 'redux-thunk'
import { logger } from 'redux-logger'

import reducer from "./src/reducers/index"

const middleware=applyMiddleware(thunk, logger)
export default store = createStore(reducer, middleware);


//reducers/index.js
const initialState = {
    isLoggedIn:false,
}
export default loginReducer=(state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

  case "LOGGED_IN":
    return { ...state, isLoggedIn:true };

  default:
    return state
  }
};


//actions.js
export const logIn = (token) => ({
  type: "LOGGED_IN",
  payload: token
})
```

My React Native app is wrapped like this:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'

/**
 * Wrap App in Redux Provider
 */
const MainApp = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
)
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SalesforcegoesmobleReactNative', () => MainApp);
```

And finally my Component I expect to update state and rerender after state-change:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import { logIn } from '../actions/actions';

@connect(
    (state) => {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
        }
    },
    (dispatch) => {
        return {
            updateLogin: id => dispatch(logIn(id))
        }
    }
)
export class InvoiceList extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log("rendering...")
        return (
            <View>
                <Button title="Update Login" onPress={() => this.props.updateLogin("test")} />
                <Text>{this.props.isLoggedIn ? "true" : "false"}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

So as you can see the state changes correctly.
But after that I expect the component to render again ("rendering..." in console and in the Text-Tags to show true instead of false)

I dont see the mistake. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try defining your isLoggedIn value like that in your `connect`:

```
(state) => {
        return {
            isLoggedIn: state.loginReducer.isLoggedIn
        }
    }
```